# Custom Nagios RPM fails to login

Tags: rpm, nagios, rpmbuild

I'm creating my own Nagios RPM but I'm new to packaging. My RPM file created successfully and i'm able to install it.

When going to localhost/nagios I'm not able to login.

This is my spec file

```
%define debug_package %{nil}
%define _prefix /usr/local/nagios
%define _install /usr/bin/install
%define _httpdconf /etc/httpd/conf.d
%define _libexecdir /usr/local/nagios/libexec
%define _logdir /usr/local/nagios/var
%define _checkresultdir /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/checkresults

Summary: Nagios blabla
Name: nagios
Version: 1
Release: 1
License: PROPRIETARY
Group: Applications/Accessories
Source: nagios-1.tar.gz
Packager: Nicholas Lievens <lievens.nicholas@gmail.com>
AutoReqProv: no
Requires: gcc gcc-c++ glibc glibc-common glibc-devel gd gd-devel php53 php53-cli php53-mysql php53-gd php53-pdo graphviz httpd libdbi-dbd-mysql libdbi-devel mysql mysql-server mysql-devel git

%description
Nagios!
%prep
%setup
%build
./configure --with-init-dir=/etc/init.d \
--with-cgiurl=/nagios/cgi-bin \
--with-htmurl=/nagios \
--with-lockfile=/var/run/nagios.pid \
--with-nagios-user=nagios \
--with-nagios-group=nagios \
--prefix=%{_prefix} \
--exec-prefix=%{_prefix}/sbin \
--bindir=%{_prefix}/sbin \
--sbindir=%{_prefix}/sbin \
--libexecdir=%{_prefix}/libexec \
--datadir=%{_prefix}/share/nagios \
--sysconfdir=/etc/nagios \
--localstatedir=/var/log/nagios
make all
%install
make install
make install-init
make install-config
make install-commandmode
make install-webconf
make install-devel

htpasswd -b -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin nagiosadmin

install -d -m 0775 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/var/spool/nagios
install -d -m 0755 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_prefix}/include/nagios
install -d -m 0755 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/etc/init.d
install -d -m 0755 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/etc/logrotate.d
install -d -m 0755 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/etc/httpd/conf.d
install -d -m 0755 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_prefix}/etc
install -d -m 0755 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_prefix}/etc
%files
/etc/init.d/nagios
%{_prefix}/var
%{_prefix}/var/spool/checkresults
%{_prefix}/etc
%{_prefix}/bin
%{_prefix}/sbin
%{_prefix}/libexec
%{_prefix}/lib
%{_prefix}/include/nagios
%{_prefix}/share
%{_prefix}/etc
/etc/nagios
/etc/nagios/objects
%defattr(755,nagios,nagios)
/var/log/nagios
/var/log/nagios/archives
%defattr(2775,nagios,nagios)
/var/spool/nagios
###%files www
%defattr(755,root,root)
%{_prefix}/sbin
%{_prefix}/sbin/*
%{_prefix}/share/nagios
%defattr(-,root,root)
%{_prefix}/share/nagios/*
%config(noreplace) /etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf
```

It is possible that I'm missing some files to run nagios correctly but as I said I'm not experienced with this so if anyone knows more... Thx

--Edit
When looking into the log file I'm getting the error: Error: Could not open external command file for reading via open():(13) -> Permission Denied

Seems I have to chmod something, but what?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific when you say you cannot log on?

For starters, I would add an `apachectl condrestart` to `%post` and `%postun` to make sure `httpd` reloads the config file you dropped in.

What are the permissions on `/etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf`? Do you have to fix an SELinux context on that file?